# Problem with SELECT query (NodeJs and mySQL)

Tags: mysql, node.js

got a problem with simple user Login application. There goes the code.

```
exports.postLogIn = (req,res,next) =>{
    const reqName = req.body.name;
    const reqPassword = req.body.password;
    console.log(reqName,reqPassword);

    db.query('SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE name = ? AND password = ?', [reqName, reqPassword], function(error, results, fields) {
        console.log(results.toString());
        console.log(error);
        console.log('qirwoe');
        res.end();
    });
    // User.userRequest(reqName,reqPassword, userInfo =>{
    //     console.log();
    //     if(userInfo.length>0){
    //         console.log('fail');
    //         // return res.render('user/fail')
    //     }
    //     console.log('aproved!');
    //     // return res.render('user/index',{user:userInfo,pageTitle:'Social Reporter',path:'/'})
    //     res.redirect('/');
    // });
}
```

So, its not working at all, I dont get any response from console.logs or anything.

Here's what I observed,

```
SELECT * 
FROM userinfo 
WHERE name = 'Gui' AND password = '123465'
```

running this code on mySQL does work. I get a response back on mySQL workbench.

- I can INSERT things normally on my DB. So the connection is working.
- I did get the right req.body, so the input on '?' mysql command is right
- I did the following command to import mysql 'npm install --save mysql2'

Anyway, dont know what else to do, let me know if I need to provide more info. Thanks for your all attention!

[image]

Comment: Don't post code as images. Instead, paste the code for your [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) into the body of the question to better help others debug your code. [Relevant Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sorry dude, im new here, gonna fix it!

Comment: How are you invoking `postLogIn()`? I suspect that there are `async` issues at play.

Comment: I saw that it could be async issues ideed by researches mate. Anyway, I invoke it by `router.post('/user/attemptLogin',userController.postLogIn);` and its called by a form `<form action="/user/attemptLogin" method="POST">`

Comment: Also, can you take out your negative vote? already corrected it. Thank you

Comment: @Guibrother32 hi, I think, you should change `response.end()` to `res.end()`. And then call `next`, if you use error handler middleware.

Comment: @Animir Indeed response was incorrect, already fixed it. Still nothing, I dont call next here, instead I called `res.redirect('/');` after `res.end()` and still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

By those who's having the same problem I will post my answer here.

So, by some researches I saw that it may be an async problem, and by @esqew comment as well.

Then I tried to remove those lines,

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE name = ? AND password = ?', [reqName, reqPassword], function(error, results, fields) {
    console.log(results.toString());
    console.log(error);
    console.log('qirwoe');
    res.end();
});
```

Which is the problem, and repleace to an async function:

```
async function loginAttempt () {
    let [rows, fields] = await db.execute('SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE name = ? AND password = ?',  [reqName, reqPassword]);
    console.log(rows);
}

loginAttempt();
```

Problem solved, be aware to sync/async funcions in mySQL querys. Again, correct me if I'm wrong with any information.

Hope I could help anyone.